# Can't detect touchpad ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I think I may have uninstalled my touchpad driver by mistake. It won't work and when I type in xinput into the terminal I don't see it there. I have a HP Pavilion g6 notebook, and when I go to the website to download the driver it is an executable. I reinstalled Ubuntu on my laptop but the touchpad still doesn't work/won't be detected.

Comment: How do you think it was uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that it was disabled. From http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-Pavilion-G6-Series-Synaptics-Touchpad-not-working/td-p/1706755/page/3 :

"On your TouchPad do you see an [orange light meaning] that the TouchPad has been disabled? Double tap in the upper left hand corner and that [should] enable it again."

There is also a thread on various touchpad fixes, for older versions of Ubuntu, at https://askubuntu.com/questions/6523/touchpad-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dv6?rq=1.

Finally, there seem to have been known bugs in Ubuntu with turning on/off the touchpad; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1357076.